# Session Key with spaces ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This might seem like a stupid question but can't find an answer anywhere.

In session, is it possible to have spaces in the key?

For example, when I use Session["MyKey"], I can retrieve the value. But when I use Session["My Key"], I get nothing.

So Session keys cannot contain spaces?

Comment: If they can't, i'd be surprised.  It's just a string.  (Of course, if you don't have a session variable named "My Key" (with the space), you'll get nothing back when you ask for it.  `"MyKey" != "My Key"`.)

Comment: Hi I tried with adding a value to the Session with a key with a space and it seems to work without any issue. I don't think there is any such restriction. Have you set the value using Session["MyKey"] or Session["My Key"] ? Whatever you do the key should that you use to store must be the same as the one that you use to retrieve.

Comment: Can you post the entire code with you assigning it and trying to read the value?

Answer (score 1):

I've never assigned session with keys having string but I think should be possible. Coming to your session keys, you will get those values which you have set in `Session["mykey"]` when you read `Session["mykey"]` and not `Session["my key"]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide space between session attributes.

Session["My Key"] = "Mykey";

Response.write(Session["My Key"]);

This will print value MyKey